# Is it possible to embed a SharePoint calendar into a non-SP website?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to embed a SharePoint calendar into a non-SharePoint website? The end-user does not need access to login and edit the data. I just want them to see the calendar events.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say no. As SP calendar depends on a lot of internal javascript and other resources.

But what you can do is to use REST API to query for sharepoint calendar and bring events to your external site and bind them to any other 3rd party calendar.